# Passing entity to JSP page, and how to make a form from it?

Tags: java, jsp, forms, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to use a bean marked with @Entity as a Java Bean in a jsp page?
Do I have to wrap it in an old style pojo?

Also what is the best way to make a form from a bean? I want to display a form where all the fields of the bean correspond to an input textbox.

Specifically I hate having to specify a name="bla" attribute on an input control, and then make sure I dont mistype the same "bla" in a servlet if I want to read that attribude form the request.

Is there a way to just make an jsp accept a data-bean, show a form, and on submit have the bean in updated state in a servlet?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's called [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/).  Happy reading. :)